# Samsumg galaxy note 10+ detected as tablet using boolean resources

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-galaxy

So here is my issue, i'm currently working in an Android application, this app was originated for tablet devices only but then business decided to add the possibility to show the same application (kind of differ in usage but is basically the same app) for mobile (non tablet devices). So what we did is to use a boolean value in resources files to detect if the device is tablet or handheld device (boolean in sw600 and sw7200 as true, the rest as false) this help us in the majority of the devices but......

The issue with this is that the device Samsung Galaxy note 10+ is being detected as tablet... Is there a way to avoid this issue where devices that are more like phablets this doesn't happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "boolean in sw600 and sw7200 as true, the rest as false" -- we need you to be much more precise about this. For starters, I suspect that you meant `sw720`, not `sw7200`. Also, we would need to know exactly what the resource set qualifiers are for "the rest".

Comment: Just curious, if you hard code everything to be in the phone layout, does it still look good? If it looks bad consider making another layout.